# Delete all messages from number

Tags: android, message

I want delete all messages (in, out, draft, ....) from a number.

My code is:

```
public void deleteAllMessages(String number) {

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(SMS_URI_ALL,
            new String[] { "_id", "address" }, null, null, null);

    int x = 0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String address = cursor.getString(1);
        if (address.equals(number)) {
            int delete = context.getContentResolver().delete(SMS_URI_ALL,
                    "_id=" + id, null);
            x++;
        }
    }

    Log.i(getClass().getName(), "For:" + number + " delete MSG: " + x);

}
```

EDIT:
I try with

```
I try with  `context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);`
```

But the same result...

The count of `x` is right but nothing it is deleted! Why?
How can I do for delete all messages of a number?
The version of Android what I use is 4.4.2 powered by Nexus 4.

Comment: The result of var x is right number of sms of this number...But sms are not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on same project  i used abortBroadcast() it did not delete the  sms but it stops to broadcast  to another receiver

```
Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person",
                        "date", "body" }, "read=0", null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);
                String date = c.getString(3);
                Log.e("log>>>",
                        "0>" + c.getString(0) + "  1>" + c.getString(1)
                                + "  2>" + c.getString(2) + "  3>"
                                + c.getString(3) + "  4>" + c.getString(4)
                                + "  5>" + c.getString(5));

                if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {


                    this.abortBroadcast();
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```